# TIdHTTPServer seems to be ignoring connections sometimes

Tags: delphi, http, firefox

Using Delphi XE6, I've written lots of service applications that use TIdHTTPServer.  Every now and again, a javascript file will fail to load in Firefox, and when I check the Delphi application's log, there's no mention of it.

Example:

In TIdHTTPServer.OnCommandGet, first thing I do is log the requested page.  After the page loads in Firefox, the log shows the page request, 3 CSS requests and 3 JS requests - for this example it is correct.  But sometimes, and it's usually after I haven't requested the page for a while, despite closing Firefox, and the Delphi service application, one of the JS requests is missing, and it's not loaded in Firefox, so things don't work.

Not sure if it's relevant, but one of the techniques I use is appending the file's last modified timestamp code as a parameter when requesting the file.

eg.  in the HTML, it will say `<script type="text/javascript" src="general.js?rnd=20150522155113"></script>`

I do this to ensure updates to JS and CSS files are always reloaded and not cached.

I'm not sure how to go about solving this.  The issue affects multiple delphi projects. I only use Firefox, so not sure if other browsers are affected. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do more investigation. Check the Firefox logs. Check the network logs. Figure out where the request is getting lost, or whether it ever existed. (If you don't have those other logs, then arrange to get them. I'm sure there's a Firefox development tool, and WireShark will show network activity at the client or the server.)

Comment: I installed a Firefox add-on that logs HTTP requests, and managed to get the issue to occur.  Firefox log shows requests for general.js and general.css, but neither appear in my application log.  Weirdly, the CSS in general.css was still loaded (confirmed via Web Console), but the general.js definitely was not loaded (Web Console debugger doesn't list it, and the page broke because an ajax function contained within it wasn't available).

Comment: Well done! You're one step closer to isolating the problem. Keep at it.

Comment: I haven't been able to spend the time needed to analyse Wireshark, so instead to mitigate the issue, I modified my HTTPServer class to load and embed any linked javascript and css pages directly into the page request.  This ensures all linked documents are available at the cost of removing caching, but also speeds up the server response by only needing one http request per page, plus images.